# ¿Cómo obtengo/mapeo los datos de un join en Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, maven, java-11

He de aclarar que es mi primera vez en Spring Boot, llevo ya unas horas empapándome del tema pero me encontré que al intentar hacer un SELECT de tipo JOIN , no puedo obtener la data completa de la relación entre tabla Empleado y Puesto, siempre me faltan los datos del puesto y al hacer la consulta mi clase solo arroja null.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he consultado varias guías y tutoriales pero nada me ha funcionado la verdad (o más bien no he sabido usar Entity correctamente en mis clases).
Como sea esta es mi clase Empleado:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "empleado")
public class EmpleadoTable implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "emp_id")
private Integer emp_id;
@Column(name = "emp_curp")
private String emp_curp;
@Column(name = "emp_paterno")
private String emp_paterno;
@Column(name = "emp_materno")
private String emp_materno;
@Column(name = "emp_nombre")
private String emp_nombre;
@Column(name = "emp_fec_nac")
@JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date emp_fec_nac;
@Column(name = "emp_rfc")
private String emp_rfc;
@Column(name="pue_id")
private Integer pue_id;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="pue_id")
private PuestoTable puesto;

public Integer getEmp_id() {
    return emp_id;
}

public void setEmp_id(Integer emp_id) {
    this.emp_id = emp_id;
}

public String getEmp_curp() {
    return emp_curp;
}

public void setEmp_curp(String emp_curp) {
    this.emp_curp = emp_curp;
}

public String getEmp_paterno() {
    return emp_paterno;
}

public void setEmp_paterno(String emp_paterno) {
    this.emp_paterno = emp_paterno;
}

public String getEmp_materno() {
    return emp_materno;
}

public void setEmp_materno(String emp_materno) {
    this.emp_materno = emp_materno;
}

public String getEmp_nombre() {
    return emp_nombre;
}

public void setEmp_nombre(String emp_nombre) {
    this.emp_nombre = emp_nombre;
}

public Date getEmp_fec_nac() {
    return emp_fec_nac;
}

public void setEmp_fec_nac(Date emp_fec_nac) {
    this.emp_fec_nac = emp_fec_nac;
}

public String getEmp_rfc() {
    return emp_rfc;
}

public void setEmp_rfc(String emp_rfc) {
    this.emp_rfc = emp_rfc;
}

public Integer getPue_id() {
    return pue_id;
}

public void setPue_id(Integer pue_id) {
    this.pue_id = pue_id;
}

public PuestoTable getPuesto() {
    if(puesto == null){
        puesto = new PuestoTable();
    }
    return puesto;
}

public void setPuesto(PuestoTable puesto) {
    this.puesto = puesto;
}

public EmpleadoTable(Integer emp_id, String emp_curp, String emp_paterno, String emp_materno, 
        String emp_nombre, Date emp_fec_nac, Integer pue_id, PuestoTable puesto) {
    this.emp_id = emp_id;
    this.emp_curp = emp_curp;
    this.emp_paterno = emp_paterno;
    this.emp_materno = emp_materno;
    this.emp_nombre = emp_nombre;
    this.emp_fec_nac = emp_fec_nac;
    this.pue_id = pue_id;
    this.puesto = puesto;
}

public String getProperty(String row) throws Exception {
    switch (row) {
        case "emp_id":
            return this.emp_id.toString();
        case "emp_curp":
            return this.emp_curp;
        case "emp_paterno":
            return this.emp_paterno;
        case "emp_materno":
            return this.emp_materno;
        case "emp_nombre":
            return this.emp_nombre;
        case "emp_fec_nac":
            return this.emp_fec_nac.toString();
    }
    return row;
}
```

}

y esta es mi clase Puesto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "puesto")
public class PuestoTable implements Serializable{
@Id
@Column(name = "pue_id")
private Integer pue_id;
@Column(name = "pue_nombre")
private String pue_nombre;
@Column(name = "pue_clave")
private String pue_clave;

public Integer getPue_id() {
    return pue_id;
}

public void setPue_id(Integer pue_id) {
    this.pue_id = pue_id;
}

public String getPue_nombre() {
    return pue_nombre;
}

public void setPue_nombre(String pue_nombre) {
    this.pue_nombre = pue_nombre;
}

public String getPue_clave() {
    return pue_clave;
}

public void setPue_clave(String pue_clave) {
    this.pue_clave = pue_clave;
}

public PuestoTable(Integer pue_id, String pue_nombre, String pue_clave) {
    this.pue_id = pue_id;
    this.pue_nombre = pue_nombre;
    this.pue_clave = pue_clave;
}
```

}

Si sirve de algo, esta es la manera en que obtengo mi data:

```
@Override
public List<EmpleadoTable> selectAll() {
    List<EmpleadoTable> empleados = null;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append("select emp.emp_id, emp.emp_curp, emp.emp_paterno, emp.emp_materno, ");
    str.append("emp.emp_nombre, emp.emp_fec_nac, emp.emp_rfc, emp.pue_id,");
    str.append("pue.pue_id, pue.pue_nombre, pue.pue_clave ");
    str.append("from empleado emp join puesto pue on pue.pue_id = emp.pue_id ");
    str.append("order by emp_id fetch first 15 rows only");
    try{
        empleados = jdbcTemplate.query(str.toString(), BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(EmpleadoTable.class));
    }catch(DataAccessException ex){
        throw ex;
    }
    return empleados;
}
```

Si alguien pudiese orientarme se lo agradecería mucho.

Comment: La verdad es que ORM (el mapeado automático de tablas relacionales y objetos java) es un tema que requiere algo más que unas horas y que no tiene nada que ver con Spring Boot. Así a bote pronto, por un lado, yo diría que te sobra el campo "pue_id" en la clase EmpleadoTable; y por otro, deberías emplear las clases especiales Repository para recuperar los datos de un empleado junto con su puesto, sin que tú tengas que ejecutar explicitamente un join.

Comment: Al hacerlo "manualmente" construyendo tú mismo la query no te lo va a completar el framework, no te va a cargar el objeto PuestoTable, de ahí que te salga nulo.

Comment: Yo intentaría profundizar un poco más en los conceptos teóricos de ORM y JPA y luego jugaría un poco con una aplicación spring-boot que ya refleje esos conceptos, como la clásica Pet Clinic https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic

Answer (score 0):

con configurar los atributos con las anotaciones @Column, @JoinColumn no hace falta que lo explicites en la query. Es mas podes usar la interfaz JpaRepository que utiliza estas anotaciones para crear la query que estas haciendo. Para tu caso definí estas clases e interfaces y hacé la prueba:

1. Si usas maven agregá esta dependencia o asegurate de tenerla. Si usas gradle busca la correspondiente:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

2. Crea esta interfaz llamada IEmpleadoRepository sin metodos definidos

```
@Repository
public interface IEmpleadoRepository extends JpaRepository<EmpleadoTable, Integer> {}
```

3. Creá este service llamado EmpleadoService

```
@Service
public class EmpleadoService {

    @Autowired
    private IEmpleadoRepository empleadoRepository;

    List<EmpleadoTable> getEmpleados() {
        return empleadoRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Utilizá el método de este ultimo service que creamos y ya te deberia traer la lista de empleado, yo usé findAll() pero podes usar muchos métodos mas, definidos en JpaRepository, si necesitas hacer otras consultas a la bd podes investigar sus métodos.

Comment: The bean 'IEmpleadoRepository', defined in com.example.demo.empleado.IEmpleadoRepository defined in 'arroba'EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in com.example.demo.empleado.IEmpleadoRepository defined in 'arroba'EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration and overriding is disabled. Action:

Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

Comment: que puedo hacer en este caso? ya usé la sugerencia que me arroja la consola por cierto e igualmente surge otro error